# OCaml - Trouble printing nth element of list

Tags: list, functional-programming, ocaml

I have a function that returns a list when given a string:

```
let input_string_to_list input =
  Str.split (Str.regexp "\n") input
```

I also have a function that should return the nth element of a list:

```
let rec get_nth = function 
  | h::_, 0 -> h 
  | h::t, n -> get_nth(t, n - 1) 
;;
```

I then trying to print the nth element of the list (should be a string):

```
print_string (get_nth (input_to_set_strings input) n)
```

However I get this error on compile:

```
Error: This expression has type string list but an expression was expected of type ('a -> 'b) list * int
```

I'm not understanding where I've slipped up, I'm fairly new to functional programming, any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `List.nth` exists in the stdlib, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_nth` expects one tuple rather than two separate arguments, so it should be called like

```
get_nth ([1;2;3;4], 2)
```

or

```
print_string (get_nth ((input_to_set_strings input), n))
```

in your case.

Comment: I'd add that uncurried functions are not that idiomatic - you can also define `let get_nth l n = let rec f = function ... in f (l, n)` as a fix

Comment: @ÉtienneMillon or `let rec get_nth lst n = match lst, n with...`, but I would rather use `List.nth` :)